# Get commit history of remote repository through its URL

Tags: git, git-log

Is there a way to get a remote repository's log history without cloning it or adding it to the `origin` first?

I tried `git log <repository url>`, and clearly it didn't work.

---

**UPDATE** (2019-12-15)

Following [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59349009/12276301), I found these 2 APIs from GitHub that would allow me to get a repository's commit history: [1st one](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/) from its REST API v3, [2nd one](https://developer.github.com/v4/object/commit/) from its GraphQL API v4.

Comment: If you read [the documentation for `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), you'll note that it does not suggest you can pass it a repository URL as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to get a remote repository's log history without cloning it ...

Not in Git, no.

Technically, there isn't a *log history* at all.  In Git, history *is* commits.  The commits *are* the history.  So you either have them—the commits—and therefore have the history that `git log` can show, or you don't.

Various hosting providers add their own software layers atop Git, and those may provide ways to get the parent hash IDs and commit-log-message metadata—the information that `git log` uses and shows by default—without cloning or fetching the commits.  But that's up to the hosting provider, and each one does it differently, if they do it at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Following your answer, I found 2 APIs from GitHub that would allow me to get a repository's commit history. I updated my question accordingly to include this information.